# RCA Output to AUX In?

Tags: cable, turntables

I know more or less nothing about this sort of thing, but I recently bought a cheap-ish turntable that has an RCA output, red and white.
Now, I wanna connect that to my PC so I can record the sound using software, as well as just listen to it using my PC, is this possible in any *(preferably cheap)* way?

Comment: Unless you actually have an "aux in" on your PC (presumably part of a sound card), your best bet is a "usb sound card," basically a dongle or device with input sound jacks and a usb connection to the computer. They start at quite reasonable prices.

Comment: I do have that, but that doesn't explain what I would need.

Comment: By the way, 1) Hi and welcome! and 2) this is kind of off-topic for this Stack Exchange group, since it's not really about music but about computer interfaces. You might have better luck at https://sound.stackexchange.com/ 3) If you have an audio "in" jack, it's part of an onboard sound card. Hopefully you have some kind of manual or documentation. If it's a stereo phono mini jack, maybe all you need is an rca-to-phono-mini cable: https://www.amazon.com/AmazonBasics-3-5mm-2-Male-Adapter-Stereo/dp/B01D5H8KO2/ref=asc_df_B01D5H8KO2/

Comment: @Atlas look for "jack rca cable": on one side you have a standard "headphone jack", on the others the two RCA connectors.

Comment: Thank you @AndyBonner. You answered my question :)

Comment: Welp, maybe; now you get to find out whether the signal output of your turntable is a good match (impedance level?) for your presumably-"line-in" input. But that gets out of my area of knowledge quickly. Good luck!

Comment: What exactly is the model of turntable? Some turntables might be designed for use with an external 'phono stage' preamp, which provides necessary EQ as well as amplification, while others might have a built-in preamp.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has nothing to do with music practise or theory, it's a hi-fi connectivity question. If a record deck is designed to be plugged straight into a computer it will have a USB out. Otherwise you need an RIAA preamp, then a decent USB soundcard, neither of which are on-topic for here. [BTW, aux-in is a red herring, you cannot plug a turntable even into a hi-fi amp's aux-in, only into the turntable connection… because that's the only one with the RIAA preamp]

Comment: @AndyBonner - btw, this is also off-topic at Sound Design. There's actually nowhere on Stack Exchange for "Hi-Fi" or home audio.

Comment: Electronics.se might be the closest match. And btw, turntables with phono stage and line out used to be a thing for some time when vinyl was just making the comeback.